# Swapping specified rows in a dataframe

Tags: r

I am doing a homework problem where we create a dataframe with 4 columns and 10 rows and then create a function to deal with the dataframe.

The problem states: 
Write a single function in R called “transform” that does the following:
Accepts four arguments (without default values) in the following order:
df: a dataframe.
a: an integer indicating a chosen row number.
b: an integer indicating a second/different chosen row number.
varName: The name of any variable in df.

The function should:
Ensure that a and b are valid row numbers.
If they are valid the function should swop the value in the chosen variable at row number 'a' with row number 'b'.

The code needs to be a single function.

The code should work for a dataframe with different column names as well.

```
transform <- function(df, a, b, varName){

  if(a > nrow(df) | b > nrow(df)){
    print('Invalid row numbers specified')
  }

  if(a < 1 | b < 1){
    print('Invalid row numbers specified')
  }

  v <- varName
  c <- which(colnames(df) == v)

  if(c == 1){
    x <- df[a, 1]
    y <- df[b, 1]
    df[a, 1] <- y
    df[b, 1] <- x
  }

  if(c == 2){
    x <- df[a, 2]
    y <- df[b, 2]
    df[a, 2] <- y
    df[b, 2] <- x
  }

  if(c == 3){
    x <- df[a, 3]
    y <- df[b, 3]
    df[a, 3] <- y
    df[b, 3] <- x
  }

  if(c == 4){
    x <- df[a, 4]
    y <- df[b, 4]
    df[a, 4] <- y
    df[b, 4] <- x
  }
}
```

Expected results:

```
Num <- c(1:10)
Age <- c(14,12,15,10,23,21,41,56,78,12)
Sex <- c('F','M','M','F','M','F','M','M','F','M')
Group <- letters[1:10]
datfr <- data.frame(Num, Age, Sex, Group)

datfr <- transform(datfr,1,3,"Group")
datfr <- transform(datfr,7,2,"Group")
datfr <- transform(datfr,5,10,"Group")
datfr <- transform(datfr,5,11,"Group")
[1] "ERROR: Invalid row numbers specified"
datfr
    Num      Age     Sex        Group
1    1       14       F           c
2    2       12       M           g
3    3       15       M           a
4    4       10       F           d
5    5       23       M           j
6    6       21       F           f
7    7       41       M           b
8    8       56       M           h
9    9       78       F           i
10   10      12       M           e
```

Actual results:

```
Num <- c(1:10)
Age <- c(14,12,15,10,23,21,41,56,78,12)
Sex <- c('F','M','M','F','M','F','M','M','F','M')
Group <- letters[1:10]
datfr <- data.frame(Num, Age, Sex, Group)

datfr <- transform(datfr, 1, 3, "Group")
datfr <- transform(datfr, 7, 2, "Group")
Error in if (a > nrow(df) | b > nrow(df)) { : argument is of length zero
datfr <- transform(datfr, 5, 10, "Group")
Error in if (a > nrow(df) | b > nrow(df)) { : argument is of length zero
datfr <- transform(datfr, 5, 11, "Group")
Error in if (a > nrow(df) | b > nrow(df)) { : argument is of length zero
datfr
[1] a
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j
```

Comment: Interesting problem that has you re-assigning an already base R function, called `transform`. Consider talking to teacher/professor!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the extract operators (`[[` for column and `[` for row number) to designate precise location in data frame and then convert new values with assignment `<-` operator.

```
my_transform <- function(df, a, b, varName){
  # CHECK VALIDITY OF PARAMS
  if(a > nrow(df) | b > nrow(df) | a < 1 | b < 1 | !(varName %in% colnames(df))){
    print('Invalid var name or row numbers specified')
  }
  else {
    # SELECT COLUMN AND ROW AND ASSIGN
    df[[varName]][a] <- df[[varName]][b]
  }
  return(df)
}

New_Data <- my_transform(Original_Data, 1, 5, "myColumnName")
```

Aside - If you decide to keep the name *transform*, in order to call the original base R function, add its package alias with double colon operator: `::`. But for best practices, always avoid these namespace conflicts:

```
# ADD A NEW COLUMN WITH SPECIFIED VALUE
New_Data <- base::transform(Original_Data, new_column = 1)
```

Comment: Using this solution or your own? You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform <- function(df, a, b, varName){ 

if(a > nrow(df) | b > nrow(df) | a < 1 | b < 1 | !(varName %in% colnames(df))){ # Parameter validity check
        print('Invalid column name or row numbers specified')
}

else { # select column and row and assign
    x <- df[[varName]][a] # [[ gets column number and [ gets row number
    y <- df[[varName]][b]

    df[[varName]][a] = y
    df[[varName]][b] = x
}

return(df)  }
```